# Fluidity Threshold

Tags: astrophysics

How was the fluidity threshold for giant (liquid) planets of 60 E24 kilos (about 10-15 Earth masses), which corresponds to some 30,000-40,000 km. diam., arrived at?  Buchave et al (2014), of the Harvard-Smithsonian Astrophysics Center, have  discovered 3 types of exoplanets: rocky (below 1.7 Earth diams.); liquid dwarfs (between 1.7 and 4 Earth diams., with rocky core and H-He atmospheres); and liquid giants (over 4 Earth diams.). So the new estimate is c. 9 E24, assuming a density of 2, and 11 assuming a density of 2.5.

In addition, research done by Wolfgang and Lopez (2015) indicates that rocky planets are about 1 to 1.5 earth diams., and the lower range for liquidity is about 1.5 to 2.8, with the higher range at about 3 and over, which also confirms the intermediate mass stage.

Contrary to the common terminology, which is a persistent and complete misnomer, giant planets are not mostly gaseous, they are mostly liquid, only their atmospheres are gaseous. Scientists know this but still call them 'gaseous'. Another common and gratuitous confusionism is using 'Jovian' for giant (liquid) planets; Jovian can refer only to Jupiter.

Answer (score 0):

The threshhold is determined via a [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test). From the Buchhave+2014 article you quoted:

> At various radii, we divide the sample into two
>   bins of stars hosting small and large planets, and perform a two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test to
>   determine whether the metallicities of the two distributions of host stars are not drawn randomly from
>   the same parent population. We find two significant features in the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test diagram,
>   one at 1.7 $R_{\oplus}$ with a significance of 4.5 $\sigma$ and one at 3.9 $R_{\oplus}$ with a significance of 4.6 $\sigma$, suggesting transitions between three exoplanet size regimes (Fig. 1).

In this way one can infer some information about a data population without making further assumptions about their underlying structure. This would be different in e.e. when dividing planets according to their mean densities, when mass and radius data is available.

The original article by Buchhave+2014 in Nature is paywalled, but you can read the full article preprint [on the arxive](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7695).

The rest of your post I don't get, as it seems a bit off-topic and derails your own question:
* At planetary interior temperatures and pressures, hydrogen is [supercritical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_fluid) and metallic, where the distinction between gas and fluid no longer exist.
* The nomenclature 'gaseous', 'icy' and 'rocky' planet refer to the material those planets accreted from, not their current phase state.
* Jovian planets are planets that have masses similar to that of Jupiter(320 $m_{\oplus}$), or above.
* You seem concerned about the phase states of the hydrogen and their correct naming. A fluid can be both however, gas and liquid. A fluid is anything described by the [theory of fluid dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid), and gases and liquids are phase states defined by specific chemical potentials. So I would claim you have used the wrong vocabulary, while being a bit snobbish about other peoples use of vocabulary.

Comment: Why does the last paragraph of the answer look like the questioner commenting on the answer? That is not what editing is supposed to be used for, and the paragraph is frankly rude - it seems to be a reasonable answer to the question.

Comment: @AndersSandberg: I thought so too, and others rejected this edit. But OP doesn't have the points to comment, so i guess that's the only possibility for OP to voice their opinion, that's why I allowed this edit. I frankly don't understand the tone of what OP wants to say, nor his rebuttal of my explanations, but I'm not getting into any internet fights over what is a slur or not, so I'm gonna leave it at that.

Comment: It's utterly ridiculous to say that my edit was rude. It wasn't at all rude. It's the answer by Atmospheric Prison Escape that's rude. And it's not a reasoanble answer at all. I thought I wasn't able to comment, but it appears I can (and I have transfered my paragrph). Obviously you people are not able to answer the question, and you are rude to boot, so I'm gone, and I won't be using Stack Exchange anymore.

Comment: That doen't answer the question. The K-S test has nothing to do with determining the fluidity threshold. None of my posting is off-topic, and the rest of it does not at all derail from my question. And ''snobbish'' is the opposite of my character and my attitudes. You need to refrain from flaming and using slurs. ''Jovian'' is used to mean giant planet, that is a confusionism. Also, I use ''fluidity'' to mean gaseous or liquid, because that's what it means, and an object can't be gaseous and liquid at the same time, it's either one or the other, and ''data'' is plural.